# increase margins bubbleplot ggplot2()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I´m trying to build a bubbleplot with ggplot2(). I want to increase the margins of the graph, However, altough I have tried several solutions none seens to work.

the graph is the folling

[image]

The code I´m using is the following

```
 ggplot(data,aes(Var1,Var2,fill=Var1))+
  geom_point(aes(size=Var3/3),shape=21,show.legend = FALSE)+  theme(axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=0))+
  scale_size_identity()+
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_line(linetype=2,color="black",size=0.1),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0))
```

And here is the dataset

```
  Var1 Var2       Var3
1   T_1   T1   5.014627
2  T_12   T1   3.523363
3   T_3   T1   4.583498
4   T_7   T1 220.842570
5   T_9   T1  96.106181
6   T_1   T2 156.281533
7  T_12   T2   4.296740
8   T_3   T2  17.103414
9   T_7   T2  80.447975
10  T_9   T2  54.612852
11  T_1   T3  79.213905
12 T_12   T3   4.548642
13  T_3   T3  65.326722
14  T_7   T3  67.283008
15  T_9   T3 220.642854
16  T_1   T4 268.852172
17 T_12   T4 306.466099
18  T_3   T4  66.043928
19  T_7   T4  30.752214
20  T_9   T4  38.575883
21  T_1   T5 253.413462
22 T_12   T5   3.289762
23  T_3   T5   5.201571
24  T_7   T5 106.649741
25  T_9   T5   2.034214
```

i would greatly appreciate suggestions

Comment: Something like `+ scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.1, 0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.1, 0))`? If not, you'll have to at least give a reproducible example, and clarify the "several solutions" that don't work.

Comment: What is this `data`? Where is this `Var` & `Var2`? What is this `Var3`?

Comment: Dear Axeman and hrbrmstr - I have edited the post with a dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,

Just add +scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0, 1.5).

for example:

```
gplot(data,aes(Var1,Var2,fill=Var1))+
  geom_point(aes(size=Var3/3),shape=21,show.legend = FALSE)+  theme(axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=0))+
  scale_size_identity()+
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_line(linetype=2,color="black",size=0.1),
  axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0))+scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0, 1.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try plot.margin() or legend.margin()? For example:

```
plot + theme(..., legend.margin = unit(1, "cm"))
```

or

```
plot + theme(..., panel.margin = unit(1, "cm"))
```

Comment: This won't avoid the bubbles getting cut off.